# MSI Installer UILevel = 32 (or 35) doesn't work (ORCA)

Tags: windows-installer, installation, orca

I have to run my own msi-file like:

```
>: msiexec.exe /i mypackage.msi /qb!
```

The problem is, that I can't run it from a console, because firstly I have to open the relevant setup.exe.

So I need to do this in ORCA.

I tried it with:

```
Property: UILevel = 32 (and 35)
Property: LIMITUI = 1 (2,3)
Property: ARPNOMODIFY = 1
```

Nothing works.

Clues?

Comment: Oops, my fault. Changed it ;)

Comment: Can you tell more about your setup package? You have `setup.exe` which then starts `mypackage.msi`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set an invalid value to `UILevel`.

The [valid values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are: 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: He also shouldn't be setting this property in the Property table.  The installer will manage this based on command line arguments.

Comment: But I doesn't want to use the command line. I have to call the *.exe file from the installer.
And it doesn't work with UILevel = 3. I always see the cancel button...

Comment: As far as I know you can't remove Cancel button by setting properties in the Property table — you have to use command line parameters to `msiexec.exe` to do so.

Comment: Okay. Then I can't hide the cancel button, because the setup.exe has to start the setup.msi file and I can't edit the setup.exe.